# How to disable beep in Chrome on Alt + [Key]?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, keyboard-shortcuts

If the combination Alt+[Key] does not have a fixed action, then the buzzer sounds. For example

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.altKey && e.keyCode == 90){ // Alt+Z pressed
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Alt+Z pressed');
    }
};
```

Works, but with beep. How to prevent it?

Correct example for Alt+Z and some other keys - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/, then it can be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried `e.cancelBubble = true;`, `e.returnValue = false;` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` ? And to make the function `return false;`.

Comment: in different ways - yes, but no results

Comment: I just found a script I wrote to replace accesskey attributes by a custom keydown handler. The only differences is that I use jQuery in order to do it : `$(document).bind('keydown', keyDownHandler);`, and that i set the focus on another element in the handler (I do something like `jQuery('#my_element').click();`). Can you try it with jQuery, and then to focus another element in your handler ?

Comment: if focus in address bar - beep off, but if in INPUT on page - beep on

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug with Chrome. Calling `preventDefault()` should really stop the beep, but it doesn't.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=105500

To suppress the beep in Chrome you can add an anchor with an `accesskey` attribute to your DOM, where `accesskey` is the key you press with `Alt`.

So for your example (Alt+Z) you'd add:

```
<a accesskey="Z"></a>
```

To try it out, you can run the following in your console:

```
var anc = document.createElement('a'); anc.accessKey='Z'; document.body.appendChild(anc);
```

Note the capital 'K' in `accessKey` when you're referencing the property in javascript.

`accesskey` attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_accesskey.asp

`accessKey` property: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_accesskey.asp